# How do I get a query from another file to return a bool?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am integrating the following system into my to-do app:
Every time the user opens the app, it should check whether the date stored in Cloud Firestore has been exceeded.
If this is the case, all To-Dos of the user should be reset to false.

This is the date in Cloud Firestore I’m looking for:

[image]

This function should check if the date has been exceeded:

```
Future<bool> checkTime() async{
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    var query = users.where('Startdatum', isLessThanOrEqualTo: now);
    query = query.where('userID', isEqualTo: userID);
    final querySnapshot = await query.get();
    return querySnapshot.size > 0;
  }
```

And this function should reset all To-Dos to false:

```
Future allFalse() async{
    return await users.doc(userID).get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      var updateMap = new Map();
      var toDos = doc['Level'];
      for (var item in toDos.keys) {
        updateMap[item] = false;
      }
      doc.reference.update({'Level' : updateMap});
    });
  }
```

I created both functions in a separate file (database), as you can see here:

```
class DatabaseService {
  String userID;

  DatabaseService(this.userID);

  final CollectionReference users =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  Future allFalse() async {
    return await users.doc(userID).get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      var updateMap = new Map();
      var toDos = doc['Level'];
      for (var item in toDos.keys) {
        updateMap[item] = false;
      }
      doc.reference.update({'Level': updateMap});
    });
  }

  Future<bool> checkTime() async {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    var query = users.where('Startdatum', isLessThanOrEqualTo: now);
    query = query.where('userID', isEqualTo: userID);
    final querySnapshot = await query.get();
    return querySnapshot.size > 0;
  }
}
```

I create an if condition in in inite State that includes checkTime. If checkTime returns true, the Future returns allFalse, which sets all To-Dos to false.

```
class _UebersichtState extends State<Uebersicht> {
  User? user;
  late DatabaseService database;

  Future<void> connect() async{
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    UserCredential result = await auth.signInAnonymously();
    user = result.user;
    database = DatabaseService(user!.uid);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    connect();
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () async{
        if(await database.checkTime()) {
          return await database.allFalse();}
        else print('Still time left');
      });
    }
```

I used a delay because the connect () function has to be executed first, it initializes database.

---

When I start the app, no error appears, but the To-Dos are not reset either.

Today we have the 21. 12. 2021 and in Cloud Firestore is 14. 12. 21 deposited.
The function allFalse works, it resets the To-Dos all.
It must be the function checkTime, which does not return a bool in the if condition. I just replaced it with if (0 == 0) and that triggers allFalse.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I believe this is the problem:

```
query = query.where('userID', isEqualTo: userID);
```

The above line would only work if your document had a field `userID` and said field was equal to your UID, but from what I could gather, you identify the UID by the name of the documents, if that is the case, this should work?

```
Future<bool> checkTime() async {
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  final now = DateTime.now();
  final doc = await users.doc(userID).get();
  final stufenzeit = (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['Stufenzeit'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
  final storedDate = (stufenSetit['Startdatum'] as TimeStamp).toDate();
  
  return now.compareTo(storedDate) > 0;
}
```

There's probably also a way to do it with queries, but I am not so well versed on those to be completely honest.

Comment: Looks like a good solution, but data () after doc is highlighted in red and the following error appears in the console: `Error: The method 'data' isn't defined for the class 'Future<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>> Function([GetOptions?])'.`

Comment: That's weird, the code works on my end. Are you sure you added the parenthesis in this line `final doc = await users.doc(userID).get();`? make sure you didn't write this by mistake `final doc = await users.doc(userID).get;`

Comment: That’s exactly the mistake I made. Now nothing is underlined in red. When I start the app now, it starts as normal, but the To-Dos are not reset. The console will then read: `E/flutter ( 3935): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp' in type cast`

Comment: I think that might be my bad because I forgot about Stufenzeit, I updated my answer, could you see if it works now?

Comment: It works, thank you!